# JOI validation is not returning all the errors despite setting abort early false

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js, joi

i've been trying to validate my payload via joi schema. But it's not returning the error what I've written in schema rather it's showing only one error. Even if i give payload like name=int only one custom error is showing up despite giving 2nd input aka username a integer value:

> {
>    "statusCode": 400,
>
> "error": "Bad Request",
>
> "message": "name expecting a string"
>   }

rather it should have printed

> {
>    "statusCode": 400,
>
> "error": "Bad Request",
>
> "message": "name expecting a string"/"username expecting a string"
>   }

this is my code:
server.js

```
    const server = Hapi.server({
        port: 3000,
        routes: {
            validate: {
                options: {
                    abortEarly: false
                  },
                failAction: async (request, response, err) => {
                    throw Boom.badRequest(err.message);
                },
            },

        },
    });
```

joi-schmea.js

```
const NamePayload = Joi.object().keys({
    name: Joi.string().required().error(new Error('name expecting a string')),
    username: Joi.string().required().error(new Error('username expecting a string')),
    age: Joi.integer().required().error(new Error('age expecting a number')),

});
```

routes.js:

```
validate: {
        payload: Schema.NamePayload,

      },
```

**I want postman to show all the error message not only the first error message**. And I also dont wanna use default error message **`child must be string/int`** type error that's why I'm using new error. I've read all the stackoverflow article about that error but nothing solved my problem . This is the hapi and joi version im using:

> @hapi/joi: ^15.0.3,
>
> @hapi/hapi: ^18.3.1,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I understand, each Joi error throws a [`ValidationError`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#errors) that contains a key **details**, which is an array of errors, each one, among other things, has your custom error message, and by doing **new Error()** in your schema you are overriding that key details. So, this is what I suggest you to do:

Replace your schema errors with this:

```
Joi.object().keys({
    name: Joi.string().required().error(() => 'name expecting a string'),
    username: Joi.string().required().error(() => 'username expecting a string'),
    age: Joi.number().integer().required().error(() => 'age expecting a number'),
});
```

And then in your **failAction** concat those messages that are inside **err.details**:

```
failAction: async (request, response, err) => {
    throw Boom.badRequest(err.details.map((error) => error.message).join('/'));
}
```

For this payload:

```
{
   "name": 10
}
```

You will get this response:

```
{
   "statusCode": 400,
   "error": "Bad Request",
   "message": "name expecting a string/username expecting a string/age expecting a number"
}
```

Comment: This advice sadly does not work because: `error() must return an Error object`

Answer (score 1):

Writing this if someone finds this helpful:

use: { abortEarly: false } in joi.validate()

eg: const joiResult = joiSchema.validate(
{
name,
email,
},
{ abortEarly: false }
);